# Highlighting every clicked RadButton/Button automatically until an event is fired to remove the highlight

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a Kiosk style EPOS touchscreen app done in WPF MVVM for a client. They have put in a request for every button to be 'highlighted' (i.e. different colour border but keep button background and foreground the same as it is without touch) on screen when touched until the pay button is touched then reset the 'highlight'. I have the same colour when touched sorted via overriding the control template of the button but I cannot think of a good way to do the highlight.

My initial thought is that I would have to create a boolean property for every button on screen in my model and link a DataTrigger for that button to every specific boolean and set these booleans all to false touch of the pay button but that seems inefficient considering the amount of buttons on screen and the potential for more buttons to be added as the development cycle continues. I was wondering if there is simpler way to code this behaviour?

I have attached a current button sample from the app for reference

```
<telerik:RadButton Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Fluent"  Style="{DynamicResource QuickStakes}" 
                                   Command="{Binding UseQuickStakeCommand}" 
                                   CommandParameter="50.00">
                        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" Text="£50" ></TextBlock>
                    </telerik:RadButton>
```

And here is the style set for the button in question

```
        <Style TargetType="telerik:RadButton" x:Key="QuickStakes">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="50" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
            <Setter Property="Template">

                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="5"  Background="#df8a2d" >
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#df8a2d" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#df8a2d" />
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Note I am using Teleriks RadButton but I am open to using WPF standard buttons if this is easier to do using them.

Thanks